# How can I fix this Excel LAMBDA formula to result all SKUs and prices, type of Unpivot formula

Tags: excel, lambda, excel-formula, unpivot, excel-lambda

I'm trying to make a formula which will unpivot some price data, there would several extra columns of data later, including some SKU data, and then 3 columns of price, 3 columns of net price, and the discount amount/unit size for each corresponding row.

Currently, just trying to get a small set to work for the base of the formula, and I got it to work correctly, but only for 1 SKU out of the 3 in the list. How could I adjust this `LAMBDA` to result all 3 SKUs in this same format? Here's the `LAMBDA` I'm currently using:

```
=LAMBDA(SKU_col,FL_cols,
    LET(SCT,COUNTA(SKU_col)-2,      
        SKUA,INDEX(SKU_col,3,1):INDEX(SKU_col,SCT,1),
        FLC,INDEX(FL_cols,3,1):INDEX(FL_cols,SCT,1),     
        FLP,INDEX(FL_cols,3,2):INDEX(FL_cols,SCT,2),     
        FLU,INDEX(FL_cols,3,3):INDEX(FL_cols,SCT,3),
        SROWS,SEQUENCE(ROWS(SCT*3)),
        SR,CEILING(SROWS/3,1),
        MD,IF(MOD(SROWS,3)=0,3,MOD(SROWS,3)),
            VSTACK( HSTACK(INDEX(SKUA,SR,1),INDEX(FLC,SR,1)),
                    HSTACK(INDEX(SKUA,SR,1),INDEX(FLP,SR,1)),
                    HSTACK(INDEX(SKUA,SR,1),INDEX(FLU,SR,1))
            )))
```

Here's an image, I am using column A as the "SKU_col", and columns B:D as the "FL_cols". Column F:G show the current result of this `LAMBDA`, and Column I:J show the ideal results of this.

[image]

Edit to add the sample data:

| SKU | FLC | FLP | FLU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99999 | 100 | 0 | 20 |
| 12345 | 48 | 24 | 2 |
| 67890 | 0 | 0 | 50 |

Comment: Please provide the data as table not as picture - then it is much easier to help you.

Comment: It is a SO practice to add sample data as table (read [ask] and [repro]) - you can use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this formula:

```vb
= LET(SKU,A2:A4,FL,B2:D4,
s,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(SKU),COLUMNS(FL)*2,
     LAMBDA(r,c,IF(ISODD(c),INDEX(SKU,r),INDEX(FL,r,c/2)))),
WRAPROWS(TOCOL(s),2))
```

or as LAMBDA:

```vb
= LAMBDA(SKU,FL,
LET(
s,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(SKU),COLUMNS(FL)*2,
     LAMBDA(r,c,IF(ISODD(c),INDEX(SKU,r),INDEX(FL,r,c/2)))),
WRAPROWS(TOCOL(s),2))
)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! This works perfectly! I cleaned it up a little bit for my own use, now time to add the rest of the data and hope I don't break the code LOL... Where would you recommend adding the 3 columns for the Net pricing? That's going to be my next step, as there are discounts off of the FLC (case cost) to make a new NETC (net case cost), and then I have 3 columns just to the right of where the FL is listed.

Comment: Without seeing the data it's hard to help.

Comment: is there any way to private message? I can send you more examples or I could just edit the question, but didn't want to get in trouble for adding to the question

Comment: You should add a new question - describing the extended requirement.

Comment: Sounds good, will add a new question right now! I'll show a bit more extended column data and include the desired output of the whole result. I really appreciate your help, was banging my head trying to figure this out lol.

Comment: okay I posted the new question, if you're able to help would be much appreciated, if not that's okay, I'll try to review your code more in depth this weekend and see if I can adjust it to add the extra columns