# Extended: How to adjust this LAMBDA Excel formula to result multiple columns of price data?

Tags: excel, lambda, excel-formula, multiple-columns, excel-lambda

In relation to my last question at [How can I fix this Excel LAMBDA formula to result all SKUs and prices, type of Unpivot formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74320082/how-can-i-fix-this-excel-lambda-formula-to-result-all-skus-and-prices-type-of-u)

@Ike created this `LAMBDA` which worked perfectly for the 3 columns of normal price data, now the next step I have to figure out is adding 3 more columns of Net prices, a Unit to divide, and a bit more info per row, I've listed a few examples below.

Here's the source table data, FLC is the normal Case cost, the Discount is subtracted by this to create the NETC. The UNITC, UNITP, and UNITU are the units which the cost would be divided by in order to create the NETC (except the 0's, where I replace the `#DIV/0` error with a 0 value)

| **SKU** | **DESC** | **DISCOUNT** | UNITC | UNITP | UNITU | **FLC** | FLP | FLU | **NETC** | NETP | NETU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **99999** | **Bottle** | **5** | 1 | 0 | 5 | **100** | 0 | 20 | **95** | 0 | 19 |
| **12345** | **Case Pack** | **0** | 1 | 2 | 24 | **48** | 24 | 2 | **48** | 24 | 2 |
| **67890** | **Unit** | **2** | 0 | 0 | 1 | **0** | 0 | 50 | **0** | 0 | 48 |

This is what the data would ideally look like when complete:

| SKU | Description | UNIT | FL | DISCOUNT | NET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99999 | Bottle | 1 | 100 | 5 | 95 |
| 99999 | Bottle | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 99999 | Bottle | 5 | 20 | 5 | 19 |
| 12345 | Case Pack | 1 | 48 | 0 | 48 |
| 12345 | Case Pack | 2 | 24 | 0 | 24 |
| 12345 | Case Pack | 24 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 67890 | Unit | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 67890 | Unit | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 67890 | Unit | 1 | 50 | 2 | 48 |

And finally, here are the current results / current `LAMBDA`:

| SKU | FL |
| --- | --- |
| 99999 | 95 |
| 99999 | 0 |
| 99999 | 19 |
| 12345 | 48 |
| 12345 | 24 |
| 12345 | 2 |
| 67890 | 0 |
| 67890 | 0 |
| 67890 | 48 |

```
=LAMBDA(SKU_col,FL_cols,
    LET(SCT,COUNTA(SKU_col)-1,
        SKU,INDEX(SKU_col,2,1):INDEX(SKU_col,SCT+1,1),
        FL,INDEX(FL_cols,2,0):INDEX(FL_cols,SCT+1,0),
        s,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(SKU),COLUMNS(FL)*2,
            LAMBDA(r,c,IF(ISODD(c),INDEX(SKU,r),INDEX(FL,r,c/2)))),
            WRAPROWS(TOCOL(s),2)))
```

(Currently, this `LAMBDA` is only referencing the column for SKU, and the columns for FLC,FLP,FLU)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit different from the first solution:

```vb
=LET(SKU,A2:B4,
Discount,C2:C4,
Unit,D2:F4,
FL,G2:I4,
Net, J2:L4,
cnt,ROWS(SKU),
SKUs,INDEX(SKU,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(cnt*3)/3,0),{1,2}),
Discounts,INDEX(Discount,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(cnt*3)/3,0)),
data,HSTACK(SKUs,TOCOL(Unit),TOCOL(FL),Discounts,TOCOL(Net)),
header,{"SKU","Description","UNIT","FL","DISCOUNT","NET"},
VSTACK(header,data))
```

Comment: Ike I couldn't thank you enough this is perfect! I have a few extra columns I need to add of SKU info, but it could easily just be added into the same spot as the SKU Description info, so I'll just do that then rearrange the data as a final step. Thank you again so so much for your help!